# Shrinkwrap ngons face

Tags: modifiers

I have a ngon face (upper face of a sole):

[image]

I would like to deform this face according to another mesh:
[image]

So I thought to use a shrinkwrap (With project z>0). But as my face has only vertices "around" the sole, I cannot deform my face.

So my idea was to use ALT + P to subdivide the face. But this solution only create a vertice, central point for all faces:

[image]

So, when applying the shrinkwrap, only the outside vertices and this new vertice are moved.

Do you have an idea to make an ngons face working with shrinkwrap?

Thanks,

Maxime

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J36VR.png (Image 3 in the initial post)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have learned, ngons do not subdivide or deform well, and that is the very reason they should be avoided...

Also, the quality of the deformation is directly related to the amount of subdivisions of your mesh so you need a lot more vertices and faces.

A possible solution is to create a surface made out of quads.

Delete all the faces and subdivide (<kbd>W</kbd>) that long edge on the left side:

[image]

Make sure that you end up with an **even number** of vertices for the whole object

[image]

Select all of the vertices ( <kbd>A</kbd>)

Press the space bar and type **Grid fill** (note that if you have an odd number of vertices the grid fill operation will fail)

Then play with the values for Span

to get a nice distribution for the newly created quad faces.

[image]

The mesh will deform much better now.[image]

Comment: It's working perfectly. Thanks a lot. Answer accepted :)

Comment: @Maxime say good by to N-gons and be happy!